# Adjusting index of summation in binomial theorem

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem, inclusion-exclusion

I am working on an inclusion-exclusion problem. At some point, I've calculated the probability of a term as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{l}\binom l k \cdot \left(\frac 3 n\right)^k\left(1-\frac 3 n\right)^{l-k}$$

But of course, binomial theorem requires the index of summation to start at $0$.

I tried to change index by letting $j = k -1 \Leftrightarrow k = j + 1$ and working with that, but I'm unable to simplify the $\binom n {j + 1}$ to $\binom n j$.

Here is what I got so far:

$$\frac {\frac 3 n}{1 - \frac 3 n}\sum_{j=0}^l\frac{l-(j+1)}{j+1}\binom n j\left(\frac 3 n\right)^j\left(1-\frac 3 n\right)^{l-j}$$

But of course, I can't take out the large fraction out of the summation because it relies on $j$. How can I apply binomial theorem here?

Comment: Did you mean $n$ instead of $l$ in your summation? If not what are they?

Comment: @Igor sorry, we are drawing $l$ times from a set of $n$ balls. The probability of getting a red ball is $\frac 3 n$ and the probability of getting green ball is $1 - \frac 3 n$.

Comment: Honestly i'm still not quite sure what the question is asking but this may help you: $\sum_{k=1}^{l}\binom{l}{k} \cdot (\frac 3 n)^k \cdot(1-\frac{3}{n})^{l-k} = \sum_{k=0}^{l}\binom{l}{k} \cdot (\frac 3 n)^k \cdot (1-\frac{3}{n})^{l-k} - (1-\frac{3}{n})^l$. Essentially I add the 0-th term to the sequence and remove it outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is convenient to apply the binomial theorem as follows:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{l}}&\color{blue}{\binom{l}{k}\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^{l-k}}\\
&=\sum_{k=\color{blue}{0}}^{l}\binom{l}{k}\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^{l-k}-\binom{l}{0}\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)^0\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^{l-0}\\
&=\left(\frac{3}{n}+\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)\right)^l-\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^l\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=1-\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^l}
\end{align*}